# missing HTML information when using requests.get

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape surfline.com using python3 with beautiful soup and requests. I am using this bit of code. Additionally I am using spyder 3.7. Also I am fairly new to webscraping.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.surfline.com/surf-report/salt-creek/5842041f4e65fad6a770882e'
r = requests.get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
print(html_soup.prettify())
```

The goal is to scrape the surf height for each day. Using inspect I found the HTML section that contains the wave height. [screen shot of surfline website & HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwfhb.png) . I run the code and it prints out the HMTL of the website. When I do ctrl find to look for the section I want to scrape it is not there. My question is why is it not being printed out and how do I fix it. I am aware that some website use java to load data onto website, is that the case here.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Most likely the section you want to scrape is rendered in Javascript, and I don't think BeautifulSoup renders Javascript content.

Comment: Inspect will mislead you as it shows you a snapshot of the current DOM; not the source.

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you, just read that in my book. I see there is a difference between inspect element and view page source

Comment: @Amir Asyraf thank you, after looking through the page source I found that it relies on javascript

Comment: **https://services.surfline.com/kbyg/spots/forecasts/tides?spotId=5842041f4e65fad6a770882e&days=6** & **https://services.surfline.com/kbyg/spots/forecasts/wave?spotId=5842041f4e65fad6a770882e&days=6&intervalHours=1&maxHeights=false&sds=true**